# Kubectl logs always empty

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi, k3s

Im running a K3s on multiple RPis which works fine except for showing logs.
`kubectl logs <pod-name>` is always empty.

For testing, I'm running busybox:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  containers:
  - name: example
    image: busybox
    args: [/bin/sh, -c, 'while true; do echo $(date); sleep 1; done']
```

The pod is running, but still no logs.
I'm suspecting log2ram, which I installed to not destroy my SD-Cards in the long run.
However, I can't figure out, why this happens and how to fix this.

Comment: Is this the case for every pod? Are you able to read logs from pods in *kube-system* namespace?

Comment: Interestingly this seems to work. metrics-server in kube-systems shows some logs ar least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out, that log2ram was full.
Clearing the /var/logs folder on the hosting node resolved the problem